# How to fix "attributeerror: type object 'rpi.gpio.pwm' has no attribute 'servo' "?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, face-recognition

I am running the code I got from this link :

https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-face-recognition-treasure-box/software

I want to imply the face recognition on a raspberry pi 3 B+.

However upon the following code I get the error of :

```
self.servo = PWM.Servo()
attributeerror: type object 'rpi.gpio.pwm' has no attribute 'Servo'
```

I have tried many GPIO and other sudo installations but I'm getting nowhere

The code is :

```
import cv2

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from RPi.GPIO import PWM

import picam
import config
import face


class Box(object):
    """Class to represent the state and encapsulate access to the hardware of 
    the treasure box."""
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize lock servo and button.
        self.servo = PWM.Servo()
        GPIO.setup(config.BUTTON_PIN, RPIO.IN)
        # Set initial box state.
        self.button_state = GPIO.input(config.BUTTON_PIN)
        self.is_locked = None

    def lock(self):
        """Lock the box."""
        self.servo.set_servo(config.LOCK_SERVO_PIN, config.LOCK_SERVO_LOCKED)
        self.is_locked = True

    def unlock(self):
        """Unlock the box."""
        self.servo.set_servo(config.LOCK_SERVO_PIN, config.LOCK_SERVO_UNLOCKED)
        self.is_locked = False

    def is_button_up(self):
        """Return True when the box button has transitioned from down to up (i.e.
        the button was pressed)."""
        old_state = self.button_state
        self.button_state = GPIO.input(config.BUTTON_PIN)
        # Check if transition from down to up
        if old_state == config.BUTTON_DOWN and self.button_state == config.BUTTON_UP:
            # Wait 20 milliseconds and measure again to debounce switch.
            time.sleep(20.0/1000.0)
            self.button_state = GPIO.input(config.BUTTON_PIN)
            if self.button_state == config.BUTTON_UP:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/pwm_py.html#rpio-pwm-servo

The Servo support was added in [0.9.1](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/blame/be1942/source/RPIO/PWM/__init__.py#L151:L169) in 2013.
If you prefer to use an older version of the library,
you may find that the instructions at
https://raspi.tv/2013/rpi-gpio-0-5-2a-now-has-software-pwm-how-to-use-it
are helpful.